# How can I resolve the issue "TypeError: string indices must be integers" while trying to use a JSON file and output it in webapp?

Tags: python, json, parsing, typeerror, streamlit

I have created a webapp using streamlit. The app allows users to get different types of data of different companies. It uses an API to get the data in json format and I want to display that json data into the screen.

[image: Error]

The function to get the data from API is as below:

```
    def getFundamentalAnalysis(self):

        params = {
            'identifier': self.identifier
        }
        url = f'{API_URL}/fundamental-analysis'
        headers = {'Api-Key': API_KEY}

        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
        result = r.json()
        return result['data']['summary'][0]
```

The code works perfectly when i access the function directly in main.py using the code

```
    data = tesla.getFundamentalAnalysis()
    print(data)
    print(type(tesla.getFundamentalAnalysis()))
```

The output is as follows:

```
{'identifier': 'C82334267', 'company_id': 'C82334267', 'calendar_year': 2022, 'calendar_quarter': 4, 'filing_date': 1675123200000, 'language': 'en-US', 'analysis': "Looking at Tesla, Inc.'s financials of Q4 reflected unimpressive, mediocre results. Its growth, value, and income factors all individually appear positive and give support for optimism regarding the likelihood of continued positive performance. We therefore gave Tesla, Inc. a total score of 65 out of 100 and a HOLD recommendation."}
<class 'dict'>
```

This output is displayed in terminal. What I want to do is to take that data variable and display its contents in streamlit app.

When someone presses 'Get Data' button in streamlit app for a company, below code is triggerd:

```
if st.button('Get Data'):
    getCompanyIdentifier(selected_company_name)
    company_data = getData(selected_option)
    st.write('Details are as follows:')
    st.write(company_data)
```

The getData function is as follows:

```
    elif (option == 'Get Fundamental Analysis'):
        company = Stock(identifier=company_id)
        return company.getFundamentalAnalysis()
```

But I get error displayed when I run this.
The error message is as below:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
Traceback:
    File "c:\Users\marta\OneDrive\Desktop\desche-app\.venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
    File "C:\Users\marta\OneDrive\Desktop\desche-app\app.py", line 140, in <module>
    company_data = getData(selected_option)
    File "C:\Users\marta\OneDrive\Desktop\desche-app\app.py", line 126, in getData
    return company.getFundamentalAnalysis()
    File "C:\Users\marta\OneDrive\Desktop\desche-app\app.py", line 94, in getFundamentalAnalysis
    return result['data']['summary'][0]
```

I tried changing the code to     `result = json.loads(r.content)` ,     `return result['summary'][0]` ,     `return result['data']` and     `return result[0]`. But it didn't work.

How can I resolve this and display the data on the webapp properly?

Comment: *result* doesn't contain what you think it does. Either *result* is a list or *result['data']* is a list. Try debugging it

Comment: I tried 'print(type(result['data']))' and it gave the output <class 'dict'>.  'result['data']['summary']' is a list.  and 'result['data']['summary'][0]' is a dict.

Comment: It's interesting that the error stack says the erroneous code is *result['data']['summary']* whereas you say it's *result['data']['summary'][0]*

Comment: "debugging it" means that you **check** what the values are **at the point where the failure occurs**. For example: you could add exception handling to `getFundamentalAnalysis`, and in the `except:` block, log what the values are that caused the failure. It also helps to **read the error message**: "... must be integers" tells you that the problem happened with either the `['data']` or the `['summary']`  access (because the `[0]` access *does* use an integer), and "string indices..." tells you that `result` or `result['data']` correspondingly was a string.

Comment: Ah, the image doesn't even agree with the textual traceback. Before posting on Stack Overflow, please make sure that you can **consistently reproduce** a problem, and then show a [mre]. Before that, you have a debugging task that Stack Overflow cannot help with.